# Differences between get_media_prefix and media_url

Tags: django

What is the difference between them?

`MEDIA_URL = 'media/'`

```
<a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}uploads2/711397.png">link</a>
<a href="{% get_media_prefix %}uploads2/711397.png">link</a>
```

They seem to work exactly the same, they create the same link.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. Both are same.

`get_media_prefix` is a templatetag provided by Django by making use of settings.MEDIA_URL. The django [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/templatetags/static.py#L78) is given below:

```
def get_media_prefix(parser, token):
    """
    Populate a template variable with the media prefix,
    ``settings.MEDIA_URL``.
    Usage::
        {% get_media_prefix [as varname] %}
    Examples::
        {% get_media_prefix %}
        {% get_media_prefix as media_prefix %}
    """
    return PrefixNode.handle_token(parser, token, "MEDIA_URL")
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix) states the same:

> get_media_prefix populates a template variable with the media prefix
> MEDIA_URL